# no suitable constructor found for FileScanner(no arguments)

Tags: java

No to Java, I wrote a class to read file and count the number of words, sentences and letter in the file.
Here is my constructor

```
//default constructor
public FileScanner(File f){
    f = null;
}

//constructor (file)
public FileScanner(int word, int letter, int sentence, int averageWord){
    numWord = word;
    numLetter = letter;
    numSentence = sentence;
    average = averageWord;
    FileScanner fs = new FileScanner();
}

//constructor (String fileName)
public FileScanner(String fileName){
    name = fileName;
}
```

here is the error no suitable constructor found for FileScanner(no arguments)

Comment: why are you trying to create a object of the same class inside a constructor that doesnt make any sense, remove that line and 
on the constructor you have commented as default is actually not the default constructor. create a constructor with no arguments that will fix your problem

Comment: Can u explain what you're trying to achieve here? So we can point out what is going wrong. Currently line 11 of your code is causing the error. U need to supply a name or a file to ur constructor.

Comment: I solved it already, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You have two other Constructors one of them requires a File variable and the other one requires a String variable which is the file name and you are trying to invoke `FileScanner fs = new FileScanner();` without any parameter but java cannot find a a constructor that takes in no parameter, in order to fix this either create a new constructor with no paramter, or pass a parameter that is :-

```
FileScanner fs = new FileScanner(new File("myFile.txt"));
```

Or

```
FileScanner fs = new FileScanner("myFile.txt");
```

That will solve the (no arguments) exception, You may get other exception if the code you posted is your project code as it does nothing .... useful...

Answer (score 1):

1. @Hovercraft points out correct you are calling a constructor within a constructor.
2. If you closely look at the call made by you -

   ```
   FileScanner fs = new FileScanner(); //calls a constructor without any argument
   ```

and in-fact your default constructor is also having one parameter included as

```
public FileScanner(File f)
```

so there is no suitable constructor to what you are trying to use.

Either have a `public FileScanner(){` constructor defined or call the one with a `filename` as @Null Saint suggests.